# Finding the Global Minimum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-value, maximum, mathematical-optimization

Consider the function

```
Fn[eps_, q_, p_] := 
  1/3 (1 - eps) (Cos[2 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi (p + q)]) + 
   1/3 eps (Cos[4 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi (p - q)] + Cos[2 Pi (2 p + q)]);
```

I want to find its global minimum over the domain $0<q,p<1$. By doing

```
NMinimize[{Fn[1, q, p], 0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}]
```

I get

```
Out[]= {-0.333333, {q -> 0.5, p -> 1.}}
```

which is a local minimum, but not the global one since, for example,

```
Fn[1, 0.147, 0.705]
Out[]= -0.905069
```

How do I get the global minimum?

Comment: ``NMinimize`` searches for local minima. Use ``Minimize`` for a global one. It works for me, and it returns (when numericized): ``{-0.905075, {q -> 0.147382, p -> 0.705236}}``.

Comment: Oh I didn't know. So `NMinimize` is like `FindMinimum`? Thank you so much! I guess the only alternative in case `Minimize` doesn't work is to actual work the minima by their definition, correct?

Comment: It worked, but got an error message "Unable to decide whether numeric quantities", any idea what this means?

Comment: Sorry, I have misled you.  ``NMinimize`` does _try_ to find a global minimum, but it is not guaranteed to return one (as you have witnessed it yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NMinimize[{Fn[1, q, p], 0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}, 
   Method -> #] & /@ {Automatic, "NelderMead", "RandomSearch", 
  "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing"}
%[[;; , 1]]
```

> `{-0.333333, -0.333333, -0.905075, -0.905075, -0.905075}`

Comment: Brilliant! And fast! Any way to delete duplicates? See, for example, the case of `Fn[0, q, p]`. Even with `DeleteDuplicates` I get repeated minimizers (possibly a machine error difference).

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the anylytical result with `Minimize`

```
Fn[eps_, q_, p_] = 
1/3 (1 - eps) (Cos[2 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi (p + q)]) + 
1/3 eps (Cos[4 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi (p - q)] + Cos[2 Pi (2 p + q)]);

{min = Minimize[{Fn[1, q, p], 0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {p, q}], 
min // N}

(*   {{1/3 (Cos[
  4 (\[Pi] + 
     ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
       Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 1/3, 0, 
        0, 0, 0}]])] + 
 Cos[2 \[Pi] ((
     2 (\[Pi] + 
        ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
          Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 1/3, 
           0, 0, 0, 0}]]))/\[Pi] - 
     ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
       Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 857/144,
         0, -(277/648), 0, 5/1296}]]/\[Pi])] + 
 Cos[2 \[Pi] ((\[Pi] + 
      ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
        Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 1/3, 0,
          0, 0, 0}]])/\[Pi] + 
     ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
       Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 857/144,
         0, -(277/648), 0, 5/1296}]]/\[Pi])]), {p -> (\[Pi] + 
 ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[
   Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 1/3, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}]])/\[Pi], 
q -> -(ArcTan[
  AlgebraicNumber[
   Root[1377 + 1395 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 857/144, 
    0, -(277/648), 0, 5/1296}]]/\[Pi])}}, 

{-0.905075, {p -> 0.705236, q -> 0.147382}}}   *)
```

With FullSimplify the result in Root form or with //ToRadicals and some selective transformations with ComplexExpand (selective to Sqrt[...] and then to ArcTan[...], I don't show here.).

```
min2 = min // FullSimplify

(*   {Root[-709 - 1692 #1 + 2124 #1^2 + 3456 #1^3 &, 1], 
{p -> (\[Pi] + 
ArcTan[Root[17 + 155 #1^2 - 109 #1^4 + 9 #1^6 &, 2]])/\[Pi], 
q -> -(ArcTan[Root[17 - 77 #1^2 + 35 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2]]/\[Pi])}}   *)

{m1 = min2[[1]] // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand, N[m1]}

(*   {-(59/288) - 
1/288 Sqrt[17017] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(62592 Sqrt[978])/1046989]] - 
1/96 Sqrt[17017/3]
Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(62592 Sqrt[978])/1046989]],  -0.905075}   *)

{pmin = 1/\[Pi] (\[Pi] + 
 ArcTan[-(1/3) Sqrt[
   109/3 - 4/3 Sqrt[481] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(162  Sqrt[978])/9253]] + 
    4 Sqrt[481/3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(162 Sqrt[978])/9253]]]]); 
pmin // N}

(*   {0.705236}   *)

{qmin = 1/\[Pi] ArcTan[
1/(Sqrt[3]) (7 (591 - 
     40 Sqrt[91] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(3 Sqrt[978])/863]] - 
     208 Cos[2/3 ArcTan[(3 Sqrt[978])/863]] + 
     40 Sqrt[273] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(3 Sqrt[978])/863]] - 
     208 Sqrt[3] Sin[2/3 ArcTan[(3 Sqrt[978])/863]]))^(1/4)]; 
qmin // N}

(*   {0.147382}   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I try the "old" method again:

```
Fn[eps_, q_, p_] := 
  1/3 (1 - eps) (Cos[2 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi q] + Cos[2 Pi (p + q)]) + 
   1/3 eps (Cos[4 p Pi] + Cos[2 Pi (p - q)] + Cos[2 Pi (2 p + q)]);

pts = FindInstance[{Grad[Fn[1, q, p], {q, p}] == 0, 0 < q < 1 && 0 < p < 1}, {q, p}, 10] // N;
criticalpts = Thread@{Fn[1, q, p] /. pts, pts}
```

[image]

There are nine critical points.

```
criticalpts[[7 ;; 8, 1 ;; 2]]
```

[image]

These are the global minima.

```
Eigenvalues@D[Fn[1, q, p], {{q, p}, 2}] /. pts
```

[image]

All together, the minima, maxima and saddles

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Fn[1, q, p], {q, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 15,MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point[{q, p, Fn[1, q, p]} /. pts[[7 ;; 8, 1 ;; 2]]],
   Blue, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point[{q, p, Fn[1, q, p]} /. pts[[6, 1 ;; 2]]],
   Blue, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point[{q, p, Fn[1, q, p]} /. pts[[9, 1 ;; 2]]],
   Green, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point[{q, p, Fn[1, q, p]} /. pts[[1 ;; 5, 1 ;; 2]]]
   }]]
```

[image]